# Why Android is not receiving FCM push notification?

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on an Android project and trying to receive Push Notifications using FCM. I implemented everything just like it is described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client), on official documentation of FCM.

I tested my work by sending demo notification from Firebase console and it worked. I used web key in my Django website and it sends notification to FCM servers and my Android app receives is properly. But there is a problem with that. App only receives notification when it is connected to Android Studio and debug app is installed and running. If I exit from debug app and try, it doesn't receive it. I changed `priority` to `hight`, added `content_available` = `true` but still not working properly.

I checked the error log in Android Studio and found this,

```
W/GCM-DMM: broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.app.android (has extras) }
```

I think GCM is playing part in the scene, and I don't know what to do to solve this error because I am not working with GCM code at all as everything is migrated to FCM. Can anyone tell me what else I need to do to start receiving push notification when my device is not connected with Android Studio and debug app is not running?

**NOTE:** My django code works fine and I see success message in response from FCM server.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Did you actually use `hight` for `priority` or is it a typo? Could you post your Android side code? :)

Comment: It is typo. But I did use `high`. I found out that it is not called when app is in background.

Comment: Do post some related code snippets and the payload like I mentioned. It' might help for us to find something.

Answer (score 5):

add this to service manifest :

```
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="true">
```

just like this :

```
     <service
        android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: @kilokahn here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element self explaining